# Compounding switch regexes in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm working on refactoring a bunch of PHP code for an instructor. The first thing I've decided to do is to update all the SQL files to be written in Drupal SQL coding conventions, i.e., to have all-uppercase keywords. I've written a few regular expressions:

```
:%s/create table/CREATE TABLE/gi
:%s/create database/CREATE DATABASE/gi
:%s/primary key/PRIMARY KEY/gi
:%s/auto_increment/AUTO_INCREMENT/gi
:%s/not null/NOT NULL/gi
```

Okay, that's a start. Now I just open every SQL file in Vim, run all five regular expressions, and save. This feels like five times the work it should be. Can they be compounded in to one obnoxiously long but easily copy-pastable regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why do you have to do it in vim? how about sed/awk?

e.g. with sed

```
sed -e 's/create table/\U&/g' -e's/not null/\U&/g' -e 's/.../\U&/' *.sql
```

btw, in vi you may do

```
:%s/create table/\U&/g
```

to change case, well save some typing.

**update**

if you really want a long command to execute in vi, maybe you could try:

```
:%s/create table\|create database\|foo\|bar\|blah/\U&/g
```

Comment: Don't you think that you answer not the question that has been asked?  Does your reply explain how to execute a series of already written substitutions on group of files in Vim?

Comment: @ib. I liked your answer and learned a bit from it, but in my understanding the question asked was indeed about joining the 5 regex given into a single one ("one obnoxiously long but easily copy-pastable regex").

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the file containing that substitution commands.
2. Copy its contents (to the unnamed register, by default):

   ```
    :%y
   ```
3. If there is only one file where the substitutions should be
   performed, open it as usual and run the contents of that register
   as a Normal mode command:

   ```
    :@"
   ```
4. If there are several files to edit automatically, open those
   files as arguments:

   ```
    :args *.sql
   ```
5. Execute the yanked substitutions for each file in the argument list:

   ```
    :argdo @"|up
   ```

   (The `:update` command running after the substitutions, writes
   the buffer to file if it has been changed.)

Comment: If SQL files are located in a file tree with several subfolders use `:args **/*.sql` instead of `:args *.sql`. Also, it is possible to run commands from the file using `:argdo source! the_file` or `:argdo source the_file` (1st variant needs colon at each line start).

Answer (score 0):

While sed can handle what you want (hovewer it can be interactive as you requestred by flag 'i'), vim still much powerfull. Once I needed to change last argument in some function call in 1M SLOC code base. The arguments could be in one line or in several lines. In vim I achieved it pretty easy.

You can open all php files in vim at once:

```
vim *.php
```

After that run in ex mode:

```
:bufdo! %s/create table/CREATE TABLE/gi
```

Repeat the rest of commands. At the end save all the files and exit vim:

```
:xall
```